# Histogram of all values in a list in R

Tags: r

I have a list `lst` with many objects in it. So `lst` would look something like

```
[[1]]
2 4 11
9 19 3

[[2]]
 4 12 2
17 2 13

[[3]]
6 8 2
3 1 15

[[4]]
4 2 14
17 8 20
...
[[100]]
16 8 23
12 4 13
```

and so on.

I want to create a single histogram and/or a density plot that contains every value in the list. If I try `hist(lst),` then I get the following error `Error in hist.default(lst) : 'x' must be numeric.` So I was wondering if there's a way to plot this in R?

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at the `unlist` function

Comment: Looks like each element of the list is a named vector... not clear on what you intend to do with those names.

Comment: @hrbmstr - what you suggested worked perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `unlist` function in R like this:

```
lst2 <- unlist(lst, use.names = FALSE)
hist(lst2)
```